# Swift Package imported to specific file only

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have added [Stevia](https://github.com/freshOS/Stevia) using Swift Package Manager as recommended. I am already using Cocoapods for other dependencies.

Right now I have a separate swift file in which I am importing Stevia for use in extension like this

```
import UIKit
import Stevia

extension UIView {
    func vHeight(_ points: CGFloat) {
        self.height(points)
    }
    
    func vWidth(_ points: CGFloat) {
        self.width(points)
    }
}
```

Problem is that this makes **Stevia** available in whole project. For example if I got to new ViewController and **there is no**

> **import Stevia**

, I can still access it. I wan't to get rid of this behaviour. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is not possible due the known longstanding compiler bug: **[SR-3908] Extension methods visible without importing module in a file** (https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/46493).

Once you added `import Stevia` in your project all public extentions from this module (swift package) become available in your whole module (your app) like functions that you use from `UIView` extension:

```swift
// Stevia+Size.swift

public extension UIView {
...
@discardableResult
    func height(_ points: CGFloat) -> Self {
        height(Double(points))
    }
...
}
```

But it doesn't work with types! Types from the other module (swift package) are not accessible without `import` statement in an each file where they are needed:

```swift
//import Stevia

let space = FlexibleSpace() // Error: Cannot find 'FlexibleSpace' in scope
```

So this is essence of the bug.